# How to add watermark to Screen (NSScreen) in macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am making an application that will add a watermark to the live screen on Mac. Which API should I choose? I tried NSScreen but I didn't find any method that could add a view to NSScreen.

Such app like Sakura in Mac Appstore.Please check it out,i have no idea which API should i use.

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to composite a faint image into an image of the screen (screenshot) or are you trying to overlay an image on the live display?

Comment: overlay an image on the live display,I have no idea which API should i use,Such app like Sakura in Mac Appstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to define a custom, transparent, window.

When you create the window, you specify the special `BorderlessWindowMask`. This creates a window that is a simple rectangular area on the screen with no titlebar, edges, etc.

Then you set up a bunch of properties so that

- the window floats above the other windows
- it doesn't respond to events
- it doesn't have a shadow
- its background is transparent

And so on

```
@implementation WatermarkOverlayWindow

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
{
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect
                            styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                              backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                defer:NO];
    if (self!=nil)
        {
        self.level = NSFloatingWindowLevel;
        self.ignoresMouseEvents = YES;
        self.releasedWhenClosed = NO;
        self.movableByWindowBackground = NO;
        self.alphaValue = 1.0f;
        self.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor;
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.hasShadow = NO;
        }
    return self;
}

...
```

Now you can add semi-transparent views to this window and those views will appear to float on the screen. Alternatively, you can place opaque views in this window and then change the overall `alphaValue` of the window to something less than `1.0`.

Comment: It works,but if any app enter full screen the watermark disappears !Any way to observe NSWindow.didEnterFullScreenNotification gobally?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. `NSWindowDidEnterFullScreen` is a notification sent just to the target window. But you might try different window levels. See the `NSWindowLevel` and `CGWindowLevelKey ` enums.

Comment: Another thought that occurred to me is that I believe full screen mode is actually handled by creating a new workspace. So make sure your window appears in all spaces (see `NSWindow.collectionBehavior`, particularly `NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces`).

Comment: WOW  ！！！  it works for have multiply virtual desktop,it saves my days.Still it doesn't work in full screen mode.I am actively searching soultions,you said "full screen mode is actually handled by creating a new workspace." what this means,I am searching how full screen mode works,any api refer to this?

Comment: My guess is that this won't work for full screen mode. The basic idea of full screen mode is that it excludes *all other windows*, so any window that's not that's being presented full screen isn't going to be visible, by definition.

Comment: My comment about "spaces" was that the spaces features works by creating multiple, virtual, desktops each with its own set of windows. I believed, under the hood, that full screen mode works by creating an ad hoc space for the single window that's going to be shown full screen and presents it there. But that's an implementation detail and—upon reflection—doesn't really solve this problem.

Comment: Oh，Thank you for your time, any way to break through this barrier? Is this a good idea to solve this by learning kernel extension or other API?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any more suggestions—my development is focused on *well behaved* windows, LOL. You're working against the UI the OS is designed to present, so if there's a solution it's going to be seriously hacky.

Comment: @JoeJoe I have a similar problem. Have you already found a solution? Thanks!